JetpackCompose the text input slider bias
When you input text and open the keyboard, the text cursor is displayed offset vertically from the input field. How can I resolve this problem?
I am using
composeBom = "2023.09.01"
material = "1.9.0"

together with the latest Compose version.


Welcome to stackoverflow! I edited your post to explain the problem a little better. However, your post is still lacking code. Please edit your post and include the code that you currently have.
